# Visual Studio 2010 Close DataSet Designer Bug

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a strange issue with Visual Studio.  Sometimes when I close a dataset from designer mode all of a sudden I get hundreds of errors popping up.  There are all sorts of different errors related to the dataset just closed.  To fix it I have to close VS down and reopen the dataset.  I'm worried if I try to rebuild without closing then it will save the dataset with the errors.

Any ideas why this is happening?

See this image for a list of errors:

[image]

Comment: Please explain the downvote,  what's wrong with my question?

Comment: Don't know about the downvote; but when you say all sorts of error what would some of them be? That might give a clue for someone who may have experienced similar situations. Also, does it happen even when you made no change to your dataset?

Comment: Thanks Arun,  the problem hasn't occurred today so I cant post the error messages but there are literally hundreds of them.  I remember looking into the dataset xml once and seeing that it appeared to cut off around 1/3 of the bottom section off.

Comment: Not a problem. If you do get errors next time, you can edit this post with errors.

Comment: Arun, please see the image I have added. Thanks.

Comment: wow! Does this occur just when you open it in Designer? I mean without even you modifying anything?

Comment: It occurs when I close a dataset.  It doesn't matter whether I have made changes to the dataset or not it.  And it doesn't happen all the time its very random.  I get days where it never happens and some days where it happens 3 or 4 times.  And it can happen with different datasets to, its not the same one all the time. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry that I am unable to get any clue on this. I have had a lot of issues (locking exe files, updating service references and so on) with 2010. But after VS 2010 SP1, I don't see those errors. Hope you have SP1.

Comment: Thanks Arun, actually I just checked and dont have SP1, that could definately help.  Do you want to post that as a solution?

Comment: Done. Really hope that fixes it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a lot of issues (locking exe files, updating service references and so on) with VS 2010. But after VS 2010 SP1, I don't see those errors. Hope you have SP1

Comment: Thanks, haven't had any problems since updating.  Fingers crossed.